# Apply same post format as WP JSON if ACF return format is Post Object?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-rest-api, acfpro

I've been struggling for a few days on implementing a "Related Posts" feature, and unfortunately PHP/Wordpress is not my strong suit.

Currently I am hitting this endpoint on my frontend:

```js
posts?slug=${slug}&orderby=date&order=desc&categories=4&acf_format=standard
```

This returns the main Post object with things that I would expect such as slug, status, sticky, etc. Within that object is the acf object, where I can see my related_posts array. My issue arises from the fact that these Post Objects are presented with entirely different fields, mostly prefixed with the word "post_".

I found [this Github issue](https://github.com/airesvsg/acf-to-rest-api/issues/153) over on the acf-to-rest-api plugin that is nearly identical to the issue I'm facing (I even stole their issue title!), however have so far been unable to implement it, and it's also from 2017 so I'm unsure of what is outdated.

Is there a way to return the normal WP Post JSON format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach would be to add a [filter to your Wordpress's theme `function.php`](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-add-a-filter-to-function-php/), using the [`add_filter()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/).

In your case, you could check if the `related_posts` field exists in the ACF response.
If it does, your filter would map the `related_posts` array to their corresponding WP Post JSON format and replaces the original `related_posts` field in the response.

Make sure to adjust the field names and additional fields (e.g., `yoast_head` if you are using the [Yoast SEO plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/)) according to your setup.
And you might also have to [flush WordPress caching plugins](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9516/2187/how-to-flush-wordpress-caching-plugins/) in order to test that filter.

```php
function modify_acf_to_rest_api_response($response, $request) {
    if (isset($response->data['acf']['related_posts'])) {
        $related_posts = $response->data['acf']['related_posts'];

        // Map related_posts to their WP Post JSON format
        $related_posts_json = array_map(function ($related_post) {
            $post_data = get_post($related_post->ID);
            $post_json = array(
                'id' => $post_data->ID,
                'date' => $post_data->post_date,
                'date_gmt' => $post_data->post_date_gmt,
                'guid' => $post_data->guid,
                'modified' => $post_data->post_modified,
                'modified_gmt' => $post_data->post_modified_gmt,
                'slug' => $post_data->post_name,
                'status' => $post_data->post_status,
                'type' => $post_data->post_type,
                'link' => get_permalink($post_data->ID),
                'title' => array(
                    'rendered' => $post_data->post_title
                ),
                'content' => array(
                    'rendered' => apply_filters('the_content', $post_data->post_content),
                    'protected' => false
                ),
                'excerpt' => array(
                    'rendered' => apply_filters('the_excerpt', $post_data->post_excerpt),
                    'protected' => false
                ),
                'author' => (int) $post_data->post_author,
                'featured_media' => (int) get_post_thumbnail_id($post_data->ID),
                'comment_status' => $post_data->comment_status,
                'ping_status' => $post_data->ping_status,
                'sticky' => false,
                'template' => '',
                'format' => get_post_format($post_data->ID),
                'meta' => array(),
                'categories' => wp_get_post_categories($post_data->ID),
                'tags' => wp_get_post_tags($post_data->ID),
                'yoast_head' => '', // If using Yoast SEO plugin
                '_links' => array()
            );

            return $post_json;
        }, $related_posts);

        // Replace the related_posts with the WP Post JSON format
        $response->data['acf']['related_posts'] = $related_posts_json;
    }

    return $response;
}

add_filter('rest_prepare_post', 'modify_acf_to_rest_api_response', 10, 2);
```

---

The [OP J. Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3394654/j-jackson) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76040092/apply-same-post-format-as-wp-json-if-acf-return-format-is-post-object/76066191#comment134152040_76066191):

> I am using a Tags select within ACF rather than WordPress's tags.
> How would I go about populating the Tags array with those?

That means you need to populate the `Tags` array with the ACF tags, by fetching the ACF tags field value and including it in the tags key of the `$post_json` array.

I will assume the ACF field name for tags is `custom_tags`, but do replace '`custom_tags`' with the actual field name of your ACF tags field if it's different.

```php
function modify_acf_to_rest_api_response($response, $request) {
    if (isset($response->data['acf']['related_posts'])) {
        $related_posts = $response->data['acf']['related_posts'];

        // Map related_posts to their WP Post JSON format
        $related_posts_json = array_map(function ($related_post) {
            $post_data = get_post($related_post->ID);
            $custom_tags = get_field('custom_tags', $related_post->ID); // Fetch ACF custom_tags field value

            $post_json = array(
                // ... other fields remain the same
                'tags' => $custom_tags, // Replace this line with the ACF custom_tags field value
                '_links' => array()
            );

            return $post_json;
        }, $related_posts);

        // Replace the related_posts with the WP Post JSON format
        $response->data['acf']['related_posts'] = $related_posts_json;
    }

    return $response;
}

add_filter('rest_prepare_post', 'modify_acf_to_rest_api_response', 10, 2);
```

Comment: This is fantastic, and exactly what I was looking for!  One small additional question... I am using a Tags select within ACF rather than Wordpress's tags. How would I go about populating the Tags array with those?